# How to install NuGet package in Mono

Tags: mono, nuget

I´ve installed Mono(version 3.2.8) on my Raspberry Pi 3 to execute a C# program that uploads a text file to SharePoint.
The program uses a NuGet package called Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM.

I can execute the program on my Windows Pc but i don´t know how to install that package in Mono to execute it there as well.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> restore command (NuGet CLI)
>
> Downloads and installs any packages missing from the packages folder.

Or

> install command (NuGet CLI)
>
> Downloads and installs a package into a project, defaulting to the current folder, using specified package sources.

Examples:

```
nuget restore mySolution.sln
nuget install Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM
```

- Install : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install
- Restore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-restore

Answer (score 4):

The recent versions of the Mono-environment come with `msbuild` which can restore the solution's dependencies (with `/r` or `/restore` flag):

```
$ msbuild solution.sln /restore
```

I used this in the system, where the command `whereis nuget` returns nothing (that means `nuget` is not installed)