# Which version of dll should I use

Tags: c#, dll, mono

I am working on `Debian Stable Linux (version 11.5)`, and I have installed `mono version 6.8.0.105` to compile `C# files`.

I have installed [`Accord` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord/3.8.0) from Nuget website.

It has following versions of dll files in its lib folder:

```
./net35/Accord.dll
./net35-unity full v3.5/Accord.dll
./net35-unity micro v3.5/Accord.dll
./net35-unity subset v3.5/Accord.dll
./net35-unity web v3.5/Accord.dll
./net40/Accord.dll
./net45/Accord.dll
./net46/Accord.dll
./net462/Accord.dll
./netstandard1.4/Accord.dll
./netstandard2.0/Accord.dll
```

Which one of these should I use for my system of Mono on Linux?

Comment: When you referencing a nuget package in the project, build system should select correct binaries from the package automatically. Do you have done problems when building or running your app?

Comment: I have been using command `mcs myapp.cs -r:AccordFolder/Accord.dll` , hence  directly referencing dll. How can I reference library in a general way so that compiler can use appropriate version?

Comment: With the `mcs` - you can't. But you can create full-featured project with `csproj` file and `packages.config` then use `msbuild` to restore packages and build the project (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58579333/2011071)

Answer (score 1):

The netstandard2.0 version, because it is cross platform and you can use in many kind of applications too (android, windows, linux). But I would use some build system, which selects the appropriate dll version by your projects target.